# Elementary number theory, compute this sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My first problem is the following: prove that $4|\sigma(4n+3)$ for any positive integer $n$.
This is what I tried:
if $1\le m\le n$, then  $\sigma(n)=\sum_{\gcd(n,m)=m}m;$
Now the sum of all integers less than $n$ and relative prime to it is $s=\frac{1}{2}n\phi(n)$. Hence $\sigma(n)=1+\sum_{1}^nm-s-\sum_{\gcd(n,m)=k\ne m}m$ (here $k\ne1$). So our problem reduces to find the last writtem sum...hints? If someone knows a better way to solve this, he's welcome. But I'd like someone other could help me find that sum because I'm still curious.

Answer (score 4):

Outline: Let $N=4n+3$. Then there is a prime $p$ of the form $4k+3$ such that the largest $e$ such that $p^e$ divides $N$ is odd.

Now show that $4$ divides $\sigma(p^e)$, and use the multiplicativity of $\sigma$.

Comment: why does $e$ need to be odd?

Comment: @user257425 because for any odd $k$ we have $k^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$. If there would be only primes with an even exponent, we would have that $N\equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Comment: Let $N=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}q_1^{b_1}\cdots q_l^{b_l}$ where the $p_i$ are primes of the form $4t+3$ and the $q_i$ are primes of the form $4t+1$. If all the $a_i$ are even, then $N\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok

Comment: @wythagoras: Thank you, you answered OP's question in a notationally much clearer way than I did.

Answer (score 0):

Given $N\equiv -1\pmod{4}$, we have $p\mid N$ for some prime $p\equiv -1\pmod{4}$: odd primes can only be $\pm 1\pmod{4}$, so if any prime divisor of $N$ would be $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, $N$ would be $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ too, giving a contradiction. For the same reason, we may assume that the greatest $h$ such that $p^h\mid N$, i.e. $\nu_p(N)$, is odd, but in such a case:
$$ \sigma(p^h) = 1+p+\ldots+p^h = (1+p)\left(1+p^2+\ldots+p^{h-1}\right) $$
so $(p+1)\mid \sigma(N)$ and $4\mid \sigma(N)$ follows.

We may also notice that if $N$ is odd, $\nu_2(\sigma(N))$ is at least the number of prime divisors of $\frac{N}{\square(N)}$, where $\square(N)$ is the greatest square dividing $N$, then consider a few cases.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(n)$ be the set of all positive integers less than or equal to $n$ that are coprime to $n$.  For $n>1$, show that, for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, $k\in S(n)$ if and only if $n-k\in S(n)$.